# How to list Bluetooth clients using InTheHand.Net.Bluetooth 4.0.15 in C#

Tags: c#, bluetooth

I am trying to get a list of known bluetooth connections that I have already paired to using the windows bluetooth app.

I have tried the code mentioned in earlier post i.e.:

```
public void scan()
    {
        BluetoothClient client = new BluetoothClient();
        BluetoothDeviceInfo[] devices = client.DiscoverDevices();
        foreach (BluetoothDeviceInfo d in devices)
        {
            BTDeviceList.Add(d.DeviceName);

        }
    }
```

The line  `BluetoothDeviceInfo[] devices = client.DiscoverDevices();` is causing an error in Visual Studio.

> CS0266: Cannot implicetly convert type 'System.Collection.Generic.IReadOnlyCollection<InTheHand.Net.Sockets.BluetoothDeviceInfo>' to 'InTheHand.Net.Sockets.BluetoothDeviceInfo[]'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Can any one point me in the right direction of collecting the list of devices which are known by the computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it happens because you want to convert IReadOnlyCollection to Array.

If you really need Array you can try like this

```
BluetoothDeviceInfo[] devices = client.DiscoverDevices().ToArray();
```

Also I recommend you to read this article [ReadOnlyCollections](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.readonlycollection-1?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Thanks for the info. In your opinion what's the best way to pull the list of Bluetooth devices using DiscoverDevices?

Comment: if the purpose of using this list to read all devices it is better to use IReadOnlyCollection
But if you want to change this list in future, I recommend to use Array or List.
In your method I think using IReadOnlyCollection is the best way.

Comment: Ta, I just want to collect the list of devices so I can find the device I want by name then connect to it to read data. I'll have a go using iReadOnlyCollection.

Comment: instead of using foreach, you can use LINQ methods. `BTDeviceList = client.DiscoverDevices().Select(d=>d.DeviceName).toList();`

Comment: here is the link about LINQ.
https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/query-syntax-and-method-syntax-in-linq